# Angular pre-select dropdown item based on values in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I was having some problem when trying to pre-select Angular dropdown item based on value in typescript. Here is my typescript:

```
transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex : any;
if (arborSvcTy.trim() === '501') {
    this.transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex = '1';
} else {
    console.log("COME IN ELSE");
    this.transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex = '0';
}
```

In my html, I am trying to use two-way binding:

```
<td>
     <select class="form-control" name="transferFeeTblCombBxRow" [(ngModel)]="transferFeeTblCombBxRow" [disabled]="isTransferFeeTblCombBxRowDisabled">
           <option disabled value="transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '0'">-- Please Select --</option>
           <option value="transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '1'">Charged</option>
            <option value="transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '2'">Waived</option>
     </select>
</td>
```

I managed to print out the `"COME IN ELSE"` from the console. However, the dropdown is not pre-selected at the first item.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:) And this `transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '0'` condition will return boolean variable *(true/flase)*, not the `value` for select.

```
<select class="form-control" name="transferFeeTblCombBxRow [(ngModel)]="transferFeeTblCombBxRow">
   <option disabled value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
   <option value="1">Charged</option>
   <option value="2">Waived</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
transferFeeTblCombBxRow : number = 2;
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmkv6c)

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of how a `select` dropdown seems to be incorrect. In a `select` dropdown, each `option` is given a unique `value`. This is needed so you can differentiate from the options in your dropdown. When you select one of these options, the `value` of that `option` is set to the `value` of your `select` dropdown. Using `ngModel` we bind to the `value` of the `select` dropdown.

Your template expressions would set the `option` values as `true` or `false`. You need to change the `option` values from template expressions to the actual values itself. 
You have also set the wrong variable as your `ngModel`. In your component, you are setting `transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex` while you are using `transferFeeTblCombBxRow` as your `ngModel`.

This is how your template should look.

```html
<select class="form-control" name="transferFeeTblCombBxRow" [(ngModel)]="transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex" [disabled]="isTransferFeeTblCombBxRowDisabled">
  <option value="0" disabled>-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Charged</option>
  <option value="2">Waived</option>
</select>
```

On a side note, even if you did want to evaluate a template expression, you'd have to use `[value]` or enclose your expression in `{{...}}` instead (like `[value]="transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '0'"` or `value="{{transferFeeTblCombBxRowIndex == '0'}}"`) (See [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions)).